# Grant SQL Server permissions to windows user group

Tags: sql-server

I have a windows user group called Group_RW with 5 users inside, each user will have access to management studio through this Group_RW, I need to give read and write access to this group in SQL Server.

What's the right way to assign permissions in SQL Server 2014?, for example I have another windows user group called Group_R, with this I want to make sure everybody inside will have read only access to the SQL Server objects.

If I have many databases, do I need to configure the same for each of them?

Comment: Create a database role and add the groups you want to the role. Assign the role to the various databases, not the Windows groups

Comment: ok thank you Panagiotis, do you know a good tutorial for doing that? is my first time doing this and I want to do it in the right way

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you to simply add the Windows Group as login within SQL Server and assign database role (*db_datareader or db_datawriter*) for each database as required.

Ex: Add **Group_RW** as SQL Login, Map the database roles *db_datareader* or *db_datawriter* on each database. Note that this will create an user on each database.

Comment: So I need to duplicate the group from windows into sql server too as login? but how those users inside windows group will be related to this new sql login?

Comment: When adding the login in SQL Server, You would need to resolve the Windows Group through the Active Directory. It will then let all users of the Windows group access the SQL Server.

Comment: Ex: Add <Domain>\Group_RW should be added as SQL Server Login - This will be considered as Windows Authenticated Login, instead of just creating a login as "Group_RW" - which will be considered a Standalone SQL Authenticated Login.